# monthconcatenation

Tags: code-golf

The goal is to output the number of the months given as input in a compact concatenated form which is still parsable if one knows the construction rules:

If either:

- January is followed by January, February, November or December; or
- November is followed by January or February

There must be a separator placed between.
Otherwise there should be no separator.

As such the output may be parsed. For example:

- **March, April and September** -> `349`
- **January, January and February** -> `1-1-2`
- **January, January and December** -> `1-1-12`
- **January, November and February** -> `1-11-2`
- **November, January and February** -> `11-1-2`
- **November and December** -> `1112`

Thus any run of ones is either a run of Novembers, a run of Novembers followed by a December, a run of Novembers followed by an October, or a January followed by an October. This may be parsed by looking to the right of such runs as the resulting string is read from left to right.

## Input

A list of months numbers (`[1-12]`) in any format you want (list, JSON, separated by one or more characters, entered one by one by user, …).

the same month can be present more than once.

## Output

The compact concatenated form described above. If a separator is needed, you can freely choose one.

Output examples for **January, February and March (1-2-3)**:

- `1-23` (chosen for the test cases below)
- `1 23`
- `1/23`
- `1,23`
- ...

## Test cases

```
[1]       => 1
[1, 2]    => 1-2
[2, 1]    => 21
[12]      => 12
[1, 11]   => 1-11
[11, 1]   => 11-1
[1, 1, 1] => 1-1-1
[2, 11]   => 211
[11, 2]   => 11-2
[1, 2, 3] => 1-23
[11, 11]  => 1111
[1,1,11,1,12,1,11,11,12]     => 1-1-11-1-121-111112
[10,11,12,11,11,10,1,10,1,1] => 1011121111101101-1
[2,12,12,2,1,12,12,1,1,2,12,12,2,11,2,12,1] => 2121221-12121-1-21212211-2121
```

## Rules

- As usual, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer in bytes wins.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.

Comment: `1111` is extra-ambiguous. Do you mean `1-1-1-1`, `1-1-11`, `1-11-1`, `11-1-1` or `11-11`?

Comment: I see what you mean, I added a test case. If there are so many `1`'s, it's hard to know at first, so `1111` should be `11-11` if you mean Nov-Nov. That has been shown in the test case `11-2` (not `112`) and added as an extra test case.

Comment: This would be so much easier in base 12...

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/) 96 bytes

### [Try it out here!](http://ideone.com/70XYzw)

#### Huge thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan) for shortening the answer.

#### golfed:

```
b,o=input(),""
for a,n in zip(b,b[1:]):o+=`a`+"-"*(a%10==1and a+n in(2,3,12,13))
print o+`b[-1]`
```

#### Explanation:

runs through the input, checks if the current item is a special case and if so handles it, otherwise just concatenates the input, prints the output string.

#### ungolfed:

```
input = [2,12,12,2,1,12,12,1,1,2,12,12,2,11,2,12,1]
output = ""
for i in range(len(input) - 1):
    next = input[i + 1]
    item = input[i]
    if item == 1 and (next == 1 or next == 2 or next == 11 or next == 12) or item == 11 and (next == 1 or next == 2):
        output += str(item) + "-"
    else:
        output += str(item)

output += str(input[-1])
    
print output
```

Comment: You need to take input.`b,o=input(),""` should do it.

Comment: You can use backticks in place of `str()`. You can use a zip to construct `a,n`. The if statement can be used to multiply the `"-"` (reducing the `for` to a one liner. The `if` can be replaced with `if a%10==1and a+n in(2,3,12,13)`. This gets you [all the way down to 96 bytes](http://ideone.com/70XYzw).

Comment: weren't backticks deprecated or not supported after python 2.6 or something like that?

Comment: They were deprecated at 3.0 by [PEP 3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/), the ideone link I gave is using  2.7.10.

Comment: thanks, I was thrown off by the IDE marking it as invalid, runs just fine. what did you mean by using the zip construct? what to create?

Comment: If you take a look at [my changes](http://ideone.com/70XYzw), you should see how I used `zip(b,b[1:])` to generate the pairs of `a,n` (`item,next`).

Comment: sorry didn't notice. also, if I take your suggestions (which is great btw) it's more your answer than mine, if you want to post it let me know, otherwise I can give you attribution for practically answering it.

Comment: It's fine, take it. I used the same stuff in my Jelly answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
%⁵=1a+e“£¤€Æ‘⁶ẋ⁸,⁹µ/
```

**[TryItOnline!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=JeKBtT0xYStl4oCcwqPCpOKCrMOG4oCY4oG24bqL4oG4LOKBucK1Lw&input=&args=WzIsMTIsMTIsMiwxLDEyLDEyLDEsMSwyLDEyLDEyLDIsMTEsMiwxMiwxXQ)** or [run all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=JeKBtT0xYStl4oCcwqPCpOKCrMOG4oCY4oG24bqL4oG4LOKBucK1LwrDh-G5hCTigqzhuZvigJw&input=&args=W1sxXSxbMSwyXSxbMiwxXSxbMTJdLFsxLDExXSxbMTEsMV0sWzEsMSwxXSxbMiwxMV0sWzExLDJdLFsxLDIsM10sWzExLDExXSxbMSwxLDExLDEsMTIsMSwxMSwxMSwxMl0sWzEwLDExLDEyLDExLDExLDEwLDEsMTAsMSwxXSxbMiwxMiwxMiwyLDEsMTIsMTIsMSwxLDIsMTIsMTIsMiwxMSwyLDEyLDFdXQ)

#### How?

```
%⁵=1a+e“£¤€Æ‘⁶ẋ⁸,⁹µ/ - Main link: the list
                   / - reduce
                  µ  - monadic chain separation
%⁵                   - left item mod 10
  =1                 - equal to 1? (Jan or Nov)
    a                - and
     +               - left item plus right item
      e              - is in
       “£¤€Æ‘        - jelly code page index list:  [2,3,12,13]
                           now True (1) for any of:
                               [1,1], [1,2], [1,11], [1,12], [11,1], or [11,2]
             ⁶       - literal space (the separator being used)
              ẋ      - repeated that many times
               ⁸     - left argument
                ,    - pair
                 ⁹   - right argument
```